# Excel VBA - Exit a loop from another module in an Userform

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Dear Stackoverflow users,

For a small project, i have a few modules and a User form.
In the module, i have a loop statement that calls the User form.
The Userform gives the user four options to choose from.

When selection an option a public variable (string) will be defined.
The loop will fill the string in the column.
But now the loop will not stop before everything is answered.

I would like to create an exit button because if the list is large this is quite annoying).

So I thought of creating a command button "exit" which can be clicked (in the user form) to cancel the loop.

But because this button is in the user form, this will not stop the loop, it will just shut down the current user from, but the next will be displayed after.

Do you know the best way to stop the loop from-out the user form?

I know the techniques like Goto, but should only be used for error handling and won't work because the Goto needs to be in the user form sub and I want to cancel the total loop in another module.

I'm quite stuck at this, I hope you guys can help me out.
I think it would be something simple.

Regards,
Dubblej

Comment: let the exit button set another global variable... then simply check for it inside the loop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest not to use global variables as well as `go to` statement. In your form add a function to show the form and return the user choice whether they want to continue or not. Something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private continue As Boolean

Public Function ShowDialog() As Boolean
    Me.Show 1
    ShowDialog = continue
End Function

Private Sub btnCancel_Click()
    continue = False
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub btnOK_Click()
    continue = True
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

And in your module call `ShowDialog` function and if its return value is false quit the loop:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Sub1()
    Dim form As New UserForm1

    Do
        If Not form.ShowDialog Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @Mehdi Javan, i still i'm learning VBA and for now it works. I insearted another global variable (boolean), that is also embedded in the loop. When thisone is false the loop quits. Why should i avoid the use of global variabels? They can be handy now and then :).

Comment: Global variables are error-prone, especially when your code grows. Because, they can be accessed or changed anywhere and it makes them difficult to track. The first time we define them their our intention is clear, but eventually, they may be used for other purposes as well and different usages of them may conflict and cause hard-to-find errors. You can find thorough explanation here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil